# Modelling the relationship between User and Rank models

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I am using Laravel & Eloquent.

I have two tables.

**User**

```
id, username, password, rankId
```

**Rank**

```
id, rankName
```

What would be the relationship between both of these? And, how would I possible show the relationship between both of these models using Laravel Eloquent Models? Any help would be highly appreciated.

I thought of hasOne, but then, it requires the second table (rank) to have a foreign key to the `users` table. How would I go about defining this relationship in Laravel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on User model,that will belongs to relation,like

```
public function rank()
{
  return return $this->belongsTo('App\Rank', 'rankId', 'id');
}
```

Now if you query from User model,you can get rank information like this,

```
$user = User::find(1);
var_dump($user->rank->rankName);
```

Now if you are on Rank model and you want to get all user in a specific rank,so your relation will be has many,like this

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\User', 'rankId', 'id');
}
```

Now if you query a rank,you can get user by this way

```
$ranks = Rank::find(1);
foreach($ranks->users as $user){
var_dump($user->username);
}
```

May be everything is clear to you now

Comment: Great! Thanks! I will try this now.

Comment: This answer is correct. Just a couple little corrections, though. I would pluralize the `user` relationship to `users`, since it is a `hasMany`. Additionally, your last little code snippet won't work. You've accidentally iterated over the wrong thing. You want: `$rank = Rank::find(1); foreach($rank->users as $user) { var_dump($user->username); }`.

Comment: You are right @patricus.Thanks for your comment.I did this